# how to calculate variance of GPUImage in swift?

Tags: ios, opencv, gpuimage, core-image, accelerate-framework

My goal is to calculate the blurriness of an image in [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/) way. Basically it firstly converts an image to grayscale and then convolve it with laplacian kernel, and then take a variance of it.

I currently choose GPUImage for doing this job because it has grayscale filter and convolution filter and it's easy to implement and use. I chose it over other options like CoreImage and Accelerate because they don't explicitly have grayscale filter (actually I would prefer Accelerate since it seems fastest one of the three, but I don't know how to make it happen.), and I chose it over OpenCV because it seems a pain to have C++ code to work with Swift, and it's the slowest one of all frameworks above.

But now I found that I couldn't find a way to calculate the variance of GPUImage. 
Anyone knows how to do it?

And considering my end goal, what framework is the best choice for me? 
If anyone knows how to achieve this task using Accelerate that would be awesome too!